# Is there any possibilities to realize multi-filter on WebGlPointsLayer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openlayers

I'm using React, OpenLayers & https://tileserver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html to take src for my WebGlPointLayer.
I've got a lot of data to display on the highest zoom. Now I'm going to create some filters, so following OpenLayers example (https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/filter-points-webgl.html) I've done the same for my porject.
The problem is the multiple filters realization.
Filter is done by style.variables and style.filter.

```
{
    variables: defaultVariables,
    filter: ['between', ['get', 'i'], ['var', 'volumeMnemonicsFrom'], ['var', 'volumeMnemonicsTo']],
    symbol: {
      symbolType: 'circle',
      size: [10, 10],
      color,
      rotateWithView: false,
      offset: [0, 0],
    },
  }
```

Is there any possibilities to realize multiple filters by WebGLPointsLayer style property?

Comment: Hi, did you find how to handle multi filter with WebGL on openlayers?

Comment: @So4ne, there were 2 ways to handle that:
1) Add another layer and filter data with js
2) There is the way to filter in styles, but it's too hard to work with. Totally unreadable

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is simply using 'all' expression and putting all filter definitions as parameter of it. Something like this:

```
  filter: ['all', 
    ['between', ['get', 'i'], ['var', 'volumeMnemonicsFrom'], ['var', 'volumeMnemonicsTo']],
    ['between', ['get', 'anotherFilterField'], ['var', 'minAnotherFilterField'], ['var', 'maxAnotherFilterField']],
  ],
```

you can check the source code of [expressions](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/src/ol/style/expressions.js) here. It's a pity the `all` value is missing in the original example of the WebGlPointsLayer in the openlayers [page](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/webgl-points-layer.html).